# How do get the current url in a renderaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

When I get the current url in a renderaction using

```
Request.Url.ToString()
```

It returns the url of the renderaction and not the page. Is there a way to get the current url of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ParentActionViewContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.parentactionviewcontext.aspx) property:

```
ParentActionViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString()
```

Comment: ...property of what ? -->  ControllerContext. So it's: ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();